# Build html documents from C/C++

Tags: c++, html, c

What is the best (and preferably lightweight) library out there to programatically build html documents from C/C++? I have used TinyXML before, but I thought it must be some lib more specifically aimed at html.

EDIT: I was unclear. I did not mean for documenting the C++ code, but rather to create html documents from scratch by creating tags and attributes. In my case, by "best" I mean a lightweight lib, but that gives me better error checking than just "my_file << strBodyStartTag << endl; style programming

Comment: The question is subjective. "best" means different things to different people and you're not providing any specific needs.

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure what did you mean by "*building html docs from C/C++*" but if your purpose is to create function / library reference documentation from source codes, [**Doxygen**](http://www.doxygen.nl/) should be ideal for that. It is widely used and well supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with xhtml, you should be able to keep using TinyXML.